# Difference between two approaches to query

Tags: swift, rx-swift, reactive, rx-cocoa

I've got a problem with RxSwift Scheduler:

Whats the difference between this two codes:

```
let results = query.flatMapLatest { query in
    return search(query)
}
.observeOn(MainScheduler.instance)
```

and

```
let results = query.flatMapLatest { query in
    return search(query)
        .observeOn(MainScheduler.instance)
}
```

Comment: I think the first is just incorrect

Comment: can you please add more Details to your question? at the Moment it is hard to get what you want to ask. thanks

Comment: improved formatting (seperated the two Code blocks) and writed more detailed question.

Answer (score 0):

There is not difference. You can see it for yourself:

```
_ = Observable.just()
            .observeOn(ConcurrentDispatchQueueScheduler.init(qos: .userInitiated))
            .do(onNext: {
                print(Thread.current)
            })
            .flatMap{
                Observable.just()
            }
            .observeOn(MainScheduler.instance)
            .do(onNext: {
                print(Thread.current)
            })
            .subscribe()
```

is equivalent to:

```
_ = Observable.just()
            .observeOn(ConcurrentDispatchQueueScheduler.init(qos: .userInitiated))
            .do(onNext: {
                print(Thread.current)
            })
            .flatMap{
                Observable.just().observeOn(MainScheduler.instance)
            }
            .do(onNext: {
                print(Thread.current)
            })
            .subscribe()
```

However with `subscribeOn` it **might** be a different story but it depends on how your Observables work with scheduling.